# Python: dynamically create methods based on other classes'

Tags: python, methods, dynamic

I've looked for quite a while but couldn't find a proper answer to my question:
I have a class containing methods which operate on arrays and I want dynamically create methods with a similar name in another class with a modified output.

I've got something like this so far, can anyone guide me ?

### Thanks

```
Class A():

    def__init__(self,array):
        self.data = array

    def method1(self,*args):
        newarray = whatever(self.data,*args)
        return newarray

    def method2(self,*args):
        newarray = whatever2(self.data,*args)
        return newarray
```

I want to be able to use those methods to generate new ones in a more complex class, say:

```
class B(C):    #inherits from C

    def __init__(self,[arg1,array]):
        #initialize from parent class
        C.__init__(self,[arg1,array])

        #create new methods for this class using same name
        methodnames = [element for element in dir(A) if element[0] != '_']

        for methodname in methodnames:
            ##following works but this is not the output I want here
            #self.__dict__[methodname] = getattr(A(array),methodname)

            #following doesn't work... at least not as I expect it to
            #case1
            #self.__dict__[methodname] = [arg1,getattr(A(array),methodname)]
            #case2
            self.__dict__[methodname] = list([arg1,getattr(A(array),methodname)])

a = array
#following returns a list of [arg1, method] but what I really want is [arg1,newarray]
C([arg1,array]).method1(*args)
```

---

OK, so let's try to be clearer:

Class A contains filters, takes an array and applies filter as method, returns filtered data.

Class filters()

```
def__init__(self,array):
    self.data = array

def filter1(self,*args):
    newarray = median(self.data,*args)
    return newarray

def filter2(self,*args):
    newarray = gaussian(self.data,*args)
    return newarray

...
```

In another module, I have class SpecialData, which operates on a list of x,y data (where x and y are iterables, i.e. lists, arrays...). So something like

Class SpecialData():

```
def __init__(self,[x,y]):
    self.data = [x,y]

def power(self,power):
    ypow = self.data[1]**power
    return [x,pow]

def porod(self):
    return [x**4,x**4*y]

....
```

Now, what I want is to add the filter methods contained in class filters to class SpecialData.
I could, of course do this by re-coding all filters with proper format for SpecialClass. but what I really want, is that each time a new filter is added to class filters, to make it available at runtime in class SpecialData without having to re-hard code the new filter.

So, not being very clever, I tried to read the list of available filters in class filters by:

import filters

filternames = [element for element in dir(filters) if element[0] != '_']

for fitlername in filternames:
    generate_filters_in_class_SpecialClass

How do I do this properly ?

I found a number of posts related to this, some using super(), others using SpecialData.**dict** or even setattr. Since the 2nd seemed more understandable to me, I focused on this one and came up with:

import filters

Class SpecialData():

```
def __init__(self,[x,y]):
    self.data = [x,y]

    filternames = [element for element in dir(filters) if element[0] != '_']

    for fitlername in filternames:

        self.__dict__[fitlername ] = [self.data[0],getattr(filters(self.data[1]),fitlername)]
```

Of course, this doesn't work, because the list is not callable. If I change the last line to :
self.**dict**[fitlername ] = list([self.data[0],getattr(filters(self.data[1]),fitlername)])
it returns the method as the 2nd element, rather than the result.

Note that the following works, but this is not what I want...
self.**dict**[fitlername ] = getattr(filters(self.data[1]),fitlername)

Hope this is clearer now...

Comment: 1-can't understand what you are asking for..., -2- please provide valid python code or no code at all ...

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? There's probably a better way to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make an advanced use of Python without using/knowing its advanced features, like you are borrowing techniques from another language.

This is not a criticism, but you should have a look on [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html), [Python introspection](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-pyint/index.html) or [metaclasses](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html).

I think that if you just complete your knowledge on [Python functions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) you will be easily able to solve your problem in a much simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than generating a proposed solution, you should make it clearer what you are trying to achieve.  Class A is a clear example of the starting point; please post an example of your desired ending point, e.g.

```
Class B(): 

    def__init__(self,array): 
        self.data = array 

    def method1(self,*args): 
        newarray = ComplexWhatever(self.data,*args) 
        return newarray 

    def method2(self,*args): 
        newarray = EvenBiggerWhatever2(self.data,*args) 
        return newarray 

a = A(input_array)
b = B(input_array)
print(a.method1(args))
print(b.method1(args))
```

What isn't clear is how you want to "dynamically generate" the new function "ComplexWhatever()" instead of writing the function by hand.